# A layer before controller - spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc application. Now in my project, I basically want to execute the latest request and all the previous requests are cancelled/terminated.

Currently all the cancellation code is inside my controller. But for code clarity/readability I want to port this code outside my controller. Ultimately I want a layer above, which takes requests, checks if the task is to be cancelled or not and only then forward it to the controller.

One way of doing above would be to have another controller which forwards it to the above controller. I have also heard of [Handler Interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). What is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with an interceptor if I were you. 
you can check [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/) for examples on how to implement you own